# Munkres 23.5 - empty set in relation to total disconnectedness?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Munkres 23.5 is stated as "A space X is called *totally disconnected* if
its only connected subspaces are one-point sets. Show that if X is discrete, then X is
totally disconnected. Does the converse hold?"

I'm confused about the definition of totally disconnected. I thought the empty set was trivially a connected subspace of any space X. Wouldn't this violate that X's only connected subspaces are one-point sets? In other words, should this definition also include the empty set?

Comment: Oftentimes, the reader is supposed to mentally add the word "nonempty" to statements. Here it is meant, of course, *"the only non-empty connected subspaces"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to exclude the empty set as an example of a connected space, just as $1$ is excluded from being prime. Munkres probably does this, though I don’t have a copy to hand. If he doesn’t do this, then he means for you to figure out the content of the statement for yourself without being too pedantic.